# Maven dependencies from internal and central repository

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have an internal Nexus repository in Maven where some plugins are deployed. There are some dependency jar file that are not present in the nexus repository while some are there. Is it possible to configure maven to search for the dependency jar files in internal repository and if not present search in the maven central repository.

**Update**

Made the similar configuration as in answer of JimHawkins. But still I guess its looking only in the nexus internal repositories for the dependencies. Here are some of the debus messges it prints:

```
[DEBUG] Using mirror Nexus (<internal-repo>) for central (repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror Nexus (<internal-repo>) for Nexus (my.repository.com/repo/path)
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin <plugin-name> or one of its dependencies
    could not be resolved: Failure to find org.co dehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in <internal-repo>
    was cached in the local repository
```

Comment: That is default Maven behaviour

Comment: _"...internal Nexus repository..."_ I assume, this is a Nexus repository which is located on a server in your LAN / intranet. Correct?

Comment: @michaldo - you have to tell maven explictely to look in nexus. See my answer

Comment: yes It is internal intranet repository

Comment: please provide your `pom.xml` and anonymised snippets from your `settings.xml`. Check if the server where Nexus is running has access to the internet. Did you configure proper proxy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify your personal maven `settings.xml` (located in `<HOME>/.m2`) like  shown below, maven searches your Nexus for dependencies, instead of looking in maven central rpository. If maven doesn't find them in Nexus, **Nexus will download them** from the maven central repository and than provide it to maven.

Every dependency is also stored in your local maven repository on your workstation, after maven fetched it from Nexus

You can tell Nexus to search for new artifacts not only in maven central repository, but also in other public repos (such as JBoss public repository).

See also: [Maven configuration](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/maven.html#maven-sect-single-group)
Use these settings in `settings.xml`:

```
<mirrors>
    <!--
        mirror | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a
        given repository. The repository that | this mirror serves has an ID
        that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used | for
        inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across
        the set of mirrors. | <mirror> <id>mirrorId</id>
        <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf> <name>Human Readable Name for this
        Mirror.</name> <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
        </mirror>
    -->

    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://your.internal-nexus.com/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>

</mirrors>

<profiles>    
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Made the similar configuration. But still I guess its looking only in the nexus internal repositories for the dependencies. Here are some of the debus messges it prints:
[DEBUG] Using mirror Nexus (<internal-repo>) for central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror Nexus (<internal-repo>) for Nexus (http://my.repository.com/repo/path/)
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin <plugin-name> or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.co
dehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in <internal-repo> was cached in the local repository

Comment: @ManikVij please provide additional informations in your question, not in comment. It's painful to gather information by reading comments

Comment: I've had an issue with my maven build via Jenkin CI pipeline. Dependency artefacts were being pulled via Nexus hosted proxy and caching locally on the Nexus server, but plugin dependencies kept going out to the public repos. The setting.xml above gave me the clue, I did not have pluginRepositories defined. All sorted, thanks @JimHawkins